# How to install Quake 3

Tags: software-installation

Running the latest debian distro (2012-09-18-wheezy) and latest firmware ? (rpi-update).

How to install and run a working Quake 3 game?

Kind regards

Comment: doesn't `sudo apt-get install quake3` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the directory where you will store the downloaded files:

```
cd /home/pi/
```

Download the files using wget:

```
wget http://radium.hexxeh.net/quake3.zip
wget http://www.andershizzle.com/Q3%20Demo%20Paks.zip
```

Unzip the two files you just downloaded using unzip:

```
unzip quake3.zip
unzip Q3\ Demo\ Paks.zip
```

Move all of the pak files that were extracted from Q3 Demo Paks.zip over to quake3/baseq3/ using the mv command:

```
mv baseq3/pak* quake3/baseq3/
```

Change the file permissions using chmod:

```
chmod +x quake3/start.sh
chmod +x quake3/ioquake3.arm
chmod +x quake3/ioq3ded.arm
```

Change the current directory:

```
cd quake3
```

Then you can start it with the following command:

```
./start.sh
```

Reference: http://blog.modmypi.com/2012/06/1.html

Comment: Whilst I'm guilty of not checking, we should promote good practice of checking the integrity of downloads. How would you go about that?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain None of the tutorials I checked included a hash of the source file and a quick check of the download site did not turn up one either.

Comment: That is an old description and won't work anymore

Comment: @Christian if so please post an answer with the correct information.

Answer (score 2):

This works: I was logged on as root the whole time, so remove the sudo!

1.Make sure you're up-to-date:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rpi-update 192Reboot.
```

2.Install required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install git gcc build-essential libsdl1.2-dev
```

3.Download the Quake 3 source code:

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/quake3.git
cd quake3
```

4.
Edit build.sh in quake3 directory:

```
change line 8 to this:  ARM_LIBS=/opt/vc/lib
change line 16 to this: INCLUDES="-I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads"
comment out line 19:    #CROSS_COMPILE=bcm2708-
```

5.
Do a ./build.sh

```
./build.sh
```

6.
Wait for compilation to finish, takes about 1 hour on RasPi.

7.
Find copies of the following somewhere (other guides will show you) and place in 
build/release-linux-arm/baseq3:

```
cd ..
sudo wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1816557/Q3%20Demo%20Paks.zip
sudo unzip Q3\ Demo\ Paks.zip
sudo rm Q3\ Demo\ Paks.zip
sudo mv ./baseq3/pak* ./quake3/build/release-linux-arm/baseq3/ 
sudo rm -rf ./baseq3/
```

.8. 
Run ioquake3.arm. Shoot things.

```
cd quake3
cd build
cd release-linux-arm
./ioquake3.arm
```

If your not logged in as root You might try this also before step 8 (I haven't)

7.2.Update your permissions for directFB access:     sudo usermod -a -G video [your_username]Log out, log back in. This will allow you to run game as non-root. Works with other directFB/SDL based stuff, too.

Kind Regards
Chris

Sources:
http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianQuake3
http://mitchtech.net/install-quake-3-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: You are downloading from the raspberry pi repo, yet you have to change things? Strange!

Comment: Yes, something to do updated opt/vc/lib ?